# Why should a refrigerant have low melting point?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, refrigeration

I  have been reading about refrigerants lately. I understand that a refrigerant should have a low boiling point; however, I don't understand why it should have a low melting point. My instinct was that it should have low melting point so it doesn't freeze at relatively high temperature, which will allow the refrigerant to be used in cold areas. Is that correct? and if it isn't, what is the reason?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's my instinct too, but I don't have a source to cite for it.

Comment: Melting point is also the freezing point and is lower than the boiling point for a given pressure.  If your boiling point is low, and something is lower, isn't that something also low?

Answer (score 0):

The vapor compression cycle uses a refrigerant that changes state ( gas to liquid, liquid to gas) at the temperatures appropriate to the use.

Freezer temperatures at -18 or -24 deg C but reject into ambient.

Refrigerators at -5 deg C to reject into ambient.

Building A/C to cool office space to 22 deg C and reject into ambient.

So some systems can even use propane - seen in a heat pump.